# Strange bug with custom ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I've recupered the ListView code on http://www.tutecentral.com/android-swipe-listview/.
I've adapted it for my usage. It work to a certain extent. I explain :

I add 6 elements to my list. It work !
I can delete an element with a button. 
It only works for the first 2 elements. After(the removing of 2 first elements) : the element is well removed of the list(List) but the display doesn't correspond at this list. And more, the deleted element is blocked.

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {

    List<Task> data;
    Context context;
    int layoutResID;

    final Handler handle = new Handler();// For the threads
    Runnable runab;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Task> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);

        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResID = layoutResourceId;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {



        TaskHolder holder = null;
        View   rowBack = convertView;

        holder = null;




        if(rowBack == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

            rowBack = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);

            holder = new TaskHolder();


            holder.deleteButton =(Button)rowBack.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button1);



            rowBack.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (TaskHolder) rowBack.getTag();
        }

Task itemdata = data.get(position);


title.setText(itemdata.getName());


holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   int position1 = position;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            if(position1 != -1 && position1 < data.size()) {

            remove( data.get(position1) );
                    notifyDataSetChanged();  
        }



    }
});











return rowBack;

}



    public List<Task> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Task> data) {
        this.data = null;
        this.data = data;
    }

    static class TaskHolder {

        TextView name;
        TextView priority;
        TextView deadline;
        TextView time;

        Button deleteButton;
        Button statButton;
        Button settingButton;
        Button stopButton;
    }

}
```

I know a lot of people have already ask this kind of question but here, this is not the same thing.

I don't know if this is normal but with 6 elements in my list. The getView method is only called for the position 0,1,2,3. (I see it on the LogCat); I never see the position 4 and 5 on the Logcat;

Other point, when I turn my phone, the app return in the ActivityMain in the onCreate and the display bug is fixed. But I need to do it whenever I delete an item.

Comment: The `getView()` function will be called the same number of times as there are list items visible on the screen, not as the number of elements there are in our array.

Comment: Yes, there are 6 items visible on the screen.